'JavaPackage' object is not callable when create Feature Store on Sagemaker AWS
I trying to test feature store offline on AWS Sagemaker but getting TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable.
My spark version 3.5.1 and Java version 8
bashrc set
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH

@feature_processor(
    inputs=[CSVDataSource(FAKE_S3_URI)],
    output=FAKE_FG_ARN,
    target_stores=["OfflineStore"],
)
def transform(raw_s3_data_as_df):
    current_time = int(time.time())
    transform_df = (
        raw_s3_data_as_df.withColumnRenamed('user','User')
                        .withColumnRenamed('password','PW')
                        .withColumnRenamed('name','Name')
                        .withColumn('ingest_time', lit(int(time.time())))
                    )

    transform_df.show(10)
    transform_df.printSchema()
    return transform_df
transform()

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 51
     47     transform_df.printSchema()
     49     return transform_df
---> 51 transform()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/feature_store/feature_processor/_udf_wrapper.py:62, in UDFWrapper.wrap.<locals>.wrapper()
     55 udf_args, udf_kwargs = self._prepare_udf_args(
     56     udf=udf,
     57     fp_config=fp_config,
     58 )
     60 output = udf(*udf_args, **udf_kwargs)
---> 62 self.udf_output_receiver.ingest_udf_output(output, fp_config)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/feature_store/feature_processor/_udf_output_receiver.py:78, in SparkOutputReceiver.ingest_udf_output(self, output, fp_config)
     70     return
     72 logger.info(
     73     "Ingesting transformed data to %s with target_stores: %s",
     74     fp_config.output,
     75     fp_config.target_stores,
     76 )
---> 78 feature_store_manager = self.feature_store_manager_factory.feature_store_manager
     79 try:
     80     feature_store_manager.ingest_data(
     81         input_data_frame=output,
     82         feature_group_arn=fp_config.output,
     83         target_stores=fp_config.target_stores,
     84     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/feature_store/feature_processor/_spark_factory.py:202, in FeatureStoreManagerFactory.feature_store_manager(self)
    198 @property
    199 @lru_cache()
    200 def feature_store_manager(self) -> fsm.FeatureStoreManager:
    201     """Instansiate a new FeatureStoreManager."""
--> 202     return fsm.FeatureStoreManager()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/feature_store_pyspark/FeatureStoreManager.py:32, in FeatureStoreManager.__init__(self, assume_role_arn)
     30 def __init__(self, assume_role_arn: string = None):
     31     super(FeatureStoreManager, self).__init__()
---> 32     self._java_obj = self._new_java_obj(FeatureStoreManager._wrapped_class, assume_role_arn)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/feature_store_pyspark/wrapper.py:45, in SageMakerFeatureStoreJavaWrapper._new_java_obj(self, java_class, *args)
     42 for arg in args:
     43     java_args.append(self._py2j(arg))
---> 45 return JavaWrapper._new_java_obj(java_class, *java_args)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py:86, in JavaWrapper._new_java_obj(java_class, *args)
     84     java_obj = getattr(java_obj, name)
     85 java_args = [_py2java(sc, arg) for arg in args]
---> 86 return java_obj(*java_args)

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Tried to change to another JupyterLab on a different instance and reinstall everything, but still got that error again

fix this error with install sagemaker-feature-store-pyspark-3.1 --no-binary :all: and add spark builder with config extra_jars = ",".join(feature_store_pyspark.classpath_jars()) and extra_packages= ["org.apache.hadoop:hadoopaws:3.3.1,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.3.1"]
